# How to use webbrowser module open a web site but at background in python 3?

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-3.x

I'm looking for a function that can open a web site use my default web browser. So I find the `webbrowser` module. It's working but not so good, like this:

```
>>> import webbrowser 
>>> webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')
True
>>> Created new window in existing browser session.
```

However I'm using chrome, and when I'm using chrome open a web site in the terminal, it'll display `Created new window in existing browser session.` if I have opened chrome.

But now I don't want these text, I've tried `tmp = webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')`, but it's not working.

Comment: what problem is it causing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham My problem is that I don't want display `Created new window in existing browser session.` when I open a web site.

Comment: if it is logging that line to the console you are in the only thing you can do is find that logging in the source and remove it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Hum, so I need do something like redirect the sys.strout?

Comment: I don't think redirecting stdout will work, if this is for yourself the simplest way would be to directly use subprocess, that is what webbrowser is doing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've just try it and it's not working. And now I understand how to do this, thanks :) . And, how can I close this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: For ubuntu somethng like `r =  check_call(["sensible-browser",url],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)` would work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, that is. thanks :)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like @PadraicCunningham said, I need this

```
>>> r = subprocess.getoutput("google-chrome-stable https://www.google.com/")
>>> r
Created new window in existing browser session.'
>>>
```

Very easy, I don't need use the webbrowser module. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

what i got from your question this should help you out:

```
import os
url="www.google.com"

os.system("start "+url)
```

Comment: @KevinGuan, no it is windows, I would also generally use subprocess over  os.system

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks. However `subprocess.getoutput` and `subprocess.getstatusoutput` are more useful :)

Comment: @KevinGuan, depends what you are doing  and your version of python ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah :P , and I solve this problem now. Just like you said :)